# How to get Java working in chromium or firefox

Tags: linux-mint, java, firefox, chrome, browser

I updated Java (version 1.8.0_25) and now I can't seem to get it working in chromium or FireFox.

The java plugins for Firefox and for chromium are not listed anymore.

Changing back ( via update-alternatives --config ) doesn't seem to do anything.

Firefox is version 33 and chromium is 34

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This how you can install java manually: [Download java](http://java.com/en/download/linux_manual.jsp?locale=en)

```
step 1: Download java for your system (i.e for 32 bit or 64 bit machine) 
step 2: Open Terminal and go to path where java is downloaded. it may be in downloaded to ~/Downloads. so cd ~/Downloads
step 3: now we will create directory called ‘java’ in /usr.
sudo mkdir /usr/java
step 4: Now we will move ‘jre…tar.gz’ to ‘/usr/java’.
sudo mv <JRE>…tar.gz /usr/java
Go to ‘/usr/java’ directory
cd /usr/java
step 5: We will extract now
sudo tar -zxvf <JRE>…tar.gz

The plugin file for Linux is located here:
32 bit: /usr/java/<JRE>/lib/i386/libnpjp2.so
64 bit: /usr/java/<JRE>/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so

step 6: Now installing java plugin for mozilla. Create a symbolic link to   the Java Plugin in the Firefox plugins directory.
Open terminal follow these instructions
cd ~/.mozilla
ls To check plugins directory is present or not.
if plugins directory is not created.
mkdir plugins
cd plugins
sudo ln -s /usr/java/<JRE>/lib/<amd64|i386>/libnpjp2.so .
step 7: Restart Firefox Browser.
step 8: Verify java
```

Comment: You're a wizard, Hackaholic. This did the trick. Thank you for taking the time.